# Fortran errors when using derived types

Tags: fortran, extends

I am writing some code in Fortran with derived types and encountering problem but still cannot figure out what is going wrong..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

> ```
> make -f vbld.mk
> gfortran -c gshapes.f08
> gshapes.f08:100.31:
>
>       generic, public :: get => get_ellipse,       &
>                                1
> Error: Undefined specific binding 'get_ellipse_minmax' as target of GENERIC 'get' at (1)
> gshapes.f08:136.31:
>
>       generic, public :: get => get_cylinder,      &
>                                1
> Error: Undefined specific binding 'get_cylinder_minmax' as target of GENERIC 'get' at (1)
> gshapes.f08:139.15:
>
>       procedure :: print => print_cylinder
>                1
> Error: Dummy argument 'cyld' of 'print' at (1) should be named 'elips' as to match the     
> corresponding argument of the overridden procedure
> gshapes.f08:135.15:
>
>       procedure :: set => set_cylinder
>                1
> Error: Dummy argument 'cyld' of 'set' at (1) should be named 'elips' as to match the 
> corresponding argument of the overridden procedure
> gshapes.f08:74.31:
>
>       generic, public :: get => get_rectangle,      &
>                                1
> Error: Undefined specific binding 'get_rectangle_minmax' as target of GENERIC 'get' at (1)
> gshapes.f08:118.31:
>
>       generic, public :: get => get_prism,      &
>                                1
>
> Error: Undefined specific binding 'get_prism_minmax' as target of GENERIC 'get' at (1)
> gshapes.f08:121.15:
>
>       procedure :: print => print_prism
>                1
> Error: Dummy argument 'prsm' of 'print' at (1) should be named 'rect' as to match the 
> corresponding argument of the overridden procedure
> gshapes.f08:117.15:
>
>       procedure :: set => set_prism
>                1
> Error: Dummy argument 'prsm' of 'set' at (1) should be named 'rect' as to match the 
> corresponding argument of the overridden procedure
> make: *** [gshapes.mod] Error 1
> ```

Comment: Show the relevant code.  The errors indicate that you have procedure names in your type bound generic statements rather than specific binding names; and some argument characteristic mismatches in specific binding overrides.

Answer (score 4):

A generic binding nominates specific **bindings** that can be considered when the generic binding is referenced in code.  Those specific bindings then reference specific procedures (and those specific procedures can be overridden - they might be different specific procedures in extensions).

Your generic bindings are referencing *procedure names*, not *specific binding names*. The correct approach is:

```
TYPE parent
CONTAINS
  PROCEDURE :: SpecificBindingA => ProcedureA
  PROCEDURE :: SpecificBindingB => ProcedureB
  GENERIC :: GenericBinding => SpecificBindingA, SpecificBindingB
END TYPE parent
```

In code, if there is an object declared `TYPE(parent) :: obj`, then a reference to `obj%GenericBinding` will either resolve to `obj%SpecificBindingA` or `obj%SpecificBindingB` depending on the type of the actual arguments in the reference.  The dynamic type of `obj` will then determine the actual procedure that is called for a particular specific binding.

The procedures ProcedureA and ProcedureB will need to have their first dummy argument declared appropriate so that it can be a passed object (it will have to be declared `CLASS(parent)`, have the same argument name, etc).  Any overrides in extensions of parent will need to vary the type of the passed argument appropriately, and have the characteristics of any other dummy arguments (including the dummy argument name) match.

Alternatively, maybe you just want a generic name for the specific procedures.  You do that using an interface block.

```
INTERFACE GenericName
  MODULE PROCEDURE ProcedureA
  MODULE PROCEDURE ProcedureB
END INTERFACE GenericName
```

In this case, a reference `GenericName(...)` will be resolved to `ProcedureA` or `ProcedureB` depending on the arguments in the reference.  In this case there is no dynamic lookup of the specific procedure based on the dynamic type of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
module shape
implicit none

type, public :: GCoord
  real :: x
  real :: y
  real :: z
end type GCoord

type, extends (GCoord) :: GCentr
end type GCentr

type, extends (GCoord) :: GCornr
end type GCornr

type, public :: Rectangle
  type(GCentr) :: cn
  type(GCoord) :: pa
  real :: b
  type(GCornr) :: p1, p2, p3, p4
  contains
    generic, public :: get => getu, getm
end type Rectangle

contains

subroutine getu (rect, val)
  class(Rectangle), intent(in) :: rect
  integer, intent(in) :: val
  write (*,*) 'GETU'
end subroutine getu

subroutine getm (rect, val)
  class(Rectangle), intent(in) :: rect
  complex, intent(in) :: val
  write (*,*) 'GETM'
end subroutine getm

end module shape
```

Comment: I made the example above and the error I get is rectangle.f08:52.31:

      generic, public :: get => getu, getm
                               1
Error: Undefined specific binding 'getm' as target of GENERIC 'get' at (1)